# TextBox not editing after SelectAll in vb.net

Tags: regex, vb.net, textbox, keypress, numeric

I have an issue,  The thing is I have to allow user to enter numeric value in text box up to one decimal point,

When all text selected and I try try to edit text by entering any numeric key, It wont let it change.

Here is the text box with value.
[image: Text Box with one decimal point value]

The code behind, Keypress

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    If Regex.IsMatch(TextBox1.Text, "\.\d") Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Kindly anybody help or suggest better way.

I have added this code but I am unable to restrict user not to enter more then one decimal point value.

```
 If Not ((Asc(e.KeyChar) >= 48 And Asc(e.KeyChar) <= 57) Or Asc(e.KeyChar) = 46 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) = 8 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) = 127) Then
        e.KeyChar = ""
        e.Handled = False
    End If
```

Comment: Are you testing vir only numerics?

Comment: currently I did not handle only numeric keys, but for testing I am only entering numeric values.

Comment: In your code, youa re also evaluating what is already IN the textbox, not what is "coming in" from the keyboard... don't use textbox1.text, use the e arguments.

Comment: Why do you reinvent the wheel? Use a [NumericUpDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Because Already a TextBox in place to take user input, So I cannot use UpDown..control

Comment: I see no logic in that reply. Just open the designer file and swap the type from `TextBox` to `NumericUpDown`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this: (not regex tho), but works great for numerics.

It allows for 1 x negative symbol, one fullstop (point), using backspace, and any numerics..

```
       Private Sub priceTextBox_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles priceTextBox.KeyPress
       If IsNumeric(e.KeyChar.ToString) = False Then

            If e.KeyChar.ToString = "." And priceTextBox.Text.Contains(".") Then e.Handled = True
            If e.KeyChar.ToString = "-" And priceTextBox.Text.Contains("-") Then e.Handled = True

            If e.KeyChar.ToString <> "." Then
                If e.KeyChar <> ControlChars.Back Then
                    If e.KeyChar <> "-" Then
                        e.Handled = True
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
        End Sub
```

**EDIT**

This allows for the above numerics, as well as only 1 decimal point. I kept it simple with more code lines to show steps, so you can see what actually happens. I am sure it can be improved, this is a quick and dirty version...

- Allows for Globalization of the decimal character
- Also catches a "paste" into the textbox, that normally circumvents the keypress catch routines

  ```
  Dim lastProperText As String = ""

  Private Sub priceTextBox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles priceTextBox.TextChanged

    If priceTextBox.Text = "" Then Exit Sub
    If IsNumeric(priceTextBox.Text) = False Then priceTextBox.Text = lastProperText
    If _containsDecimal(priceTextBox.Text, 2) = True Then priceTextBox.Text = lastProperText

  End Sub

  Private Sub priceTextBox_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles priceTextBox.KeyPress
      Dim decimalSeparator As String = Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator

      If IsNumeric(e.KeyChar.ToString) = False Then

          If e.KeyChar.ToString = decimalSeparator And priceTextBox.Text.Contains(decimalSeparator) Then e.Handled = True
          If e.KeyChar.ToString = "-" And priceTextBox.Text.Contains("-") Then e.Handled = True

          'allow backspace here
          If e.KeyChar = ControlChars.Back Then Exit Sub

          If e.KeyChar.ToString <> decimalSeparator Then
              If e.KeyChar <> ControlChars.Back Then
                  If e.KeyChar <> "-" Then

                      e.Handled = True

                  End If
              End If
          End If
      End If

      'BUG FIX
      If priceTextBox.SelectionStart > priceTextBox.Text.Length - 2 Then
        If _containsDecimal(priceTextBox.Text, 1) = True Then e.Handled = True
      End If
      '/BUG FIX

      'keep last good format.. we will use this in case something gets apsted in that does not meet our format...
      lastProperText = priceTextBox.Text

  End Sub

  Private Function _containsDecimal(stringtoCheck As String, decimalNumber As Integer) As Boolean

      Dim decimalSeparator As String = Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator

      'check to allow only 1 decimal point
      Dim positionOfPoint As Integer = 0

      'get position of decimal point (.)
      positionOfPoint = InStr(stringtoCheck, decimalSeparator)

      'check if there are not characters after decimal point... 
      'if nothin after decimal point, allow this keypress, 
      'if there is already something after decimal point, escape this keypress

      'get length of string after "."
      Dim stringTail As String = ""

      If Not positionOfPoint = 0 Then
          stringTail = Mid(stringtoCheck, positionOfPoint)
          If stringTail.Length > decimalNumber Then
              Return True
          End If
      End If

  End Function
  ```

Comment: :but it does not stops user to enter only one decimal point value. like I have shown in my image.

Comment: I have modified the code can you help me figure out how to Restrict up to one decimal point? Should I add TextChangedEvent?

Comment: You should note that this code doesn't support [globalization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization(v=vs.110).aspx). It fails with my `nb-NO` culture as the decimal separator is `,` not `.`. Also, it doesn't prevent the user from pasting non-numeric text into the text box.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå , yeah, the culture will be an issue. As I said, it can be extended (should be really) It's merely a proof of concept.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå, I updated the code to allow for cultureinfo. Please feel free to provide more suggestions for improvements.

Comment: @LouisvanTonder Great! Your effort deserves a +1!

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå  and DareDevil . I have now updated this code to indeed catch string "pasted" in, that do not stick the the required format... what.. I was taking a break from work stuff :-)

Comment: But Above code has bug in it, If i delete the left most non decimal value like if my TextBox = "8.3" and I want to edit the left most value , its not letting me do so.

Comment: Ahh ok, I can see that happening... here you will probably have to check cursor position in the textbox.

Comment: ok, this is getting "dirtier" by the moment... bug fix applied... One shoudl probably wrap this up neatly in a custom class with all the bells and whistles. But code works as above...

Comment: :) I will dig down , put more efforts to achieve it

Comment: Ok, but as above bug fix is applied... you CAN now edit your "8.3"

Answer (score 2):

I have tried this code:

Works Fine Now..
One Digit after decimal point, you may add \d\d to add digits in Regex

```
 Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    If TextBox1.SelectedText.Length = TextBox1.Text.Length Then
        TextBox1.Clear()
    End If
    If Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) = True OrElse Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) = True OrElse e.KeyChar = "."c Then
        If Regex.IsMatch(TextBox1.Text, "\.\d") Then
            'This makes backspace working
            If e.KeyChar = CChar(ChrW(8)) Then
            Else
                e.Handled = True
            End If
        End If
    Else
        e.Handled = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Nice and clean. Well done. Although keep in mind you can still "paste" in non numerical strings, and double digit numerics.